# django extra select to qs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, orm

How can i add addition select in queryset?

```
queryset = ActivityCollection.objects.filter(date_at__gte=from_date, date_at__lte=to_date).order_by('date_at')
```

it looks

```
{
        "date_at": "2021-11-24",
        "views": 25,
        "clicks": 1,
        "cost": "25.00"
},
```

i need to get:

```
{
        "date_at": "2021-11-24",
        "views": 25,
        "clicks": 1,
        "cost": "25.00",
        "cpc": "25"
}
```

cpc = cost / clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use property attribute in your model.
for example:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    # your fields
    views = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.IntegerField(

    @property
    def cpc(self):
        return self.cost/self.views
```